# Stream not reading string properly

Tags: c++, input, stringstream

I am a university student and recently started programming on C++, I am currently having an issue reading in a string using a stringstream.

I am reading information from a .csv file and storing the information in a class, what is puzzling me the most is that my code works perfectly for the first line of my .csv file but not for the second.

This is my class:

```
class Player {
public:
    string name;
    int points = 0;
    int gamesPlayed = 0;
    int todaysPoints = 0;
    int timesPresident = 0;
    int timesScum = 0;
    char playing = 'n';
};
```

This is how my .csv file is formatted:

> `Name;Points;Games Played;Times President;Times Scum
>   Grace;0;0;0;0
>   Gabriel;0;0;0;0`

And this is how I am reading it:

```
int readInPlayersList(Player playersList[], string filename) {
    listIn.open(filename);
    string line;
    istringstream fixedLine;
    int i = 0;
    int j;
    getline(listIn, line); //first line doesn't matter
    while (getline(listIn, line)) {
        if (listIn.eof()) { break; }
        j = 0;
        while (line[j]) {
            if (line[j] == ';') { //swapping ; by space to read in easily
                line[j] = ' ';
            }
            ++j;
        }
        fixedLine.str(line);
        cout << "Before reading, line = " << line << endl;
        fixedLine >> playersList[i].name >> playersList[i].points >> playersList[i].gamesPlayed >> playersList[i].timesPresident >> playersList[i].timesScum;
        cout << "After readng -> " << playersList[i].name << " " <<  playersList[i].points << " " <<  playersList[i].gamesPlayed << " " <<  playersList[i].timesPresident << " " <<  playersList[i].timesScum << endl; //testing output
        ++i;
    }
    return i;
    listIn.close();
}
```

As you can see, in order to find out what's wrong, I output what's in the line before reading into the class, and then I output the class members, for the first line, it reads it perfectly but not for the second and any other thereafter... See output below:

[image: Output]

I really want to know what I am doing wrong here, appreciate any help, cheers!
Gabriel Groff

Comment: Don't use raw c-style arrays, prefer using `std::array` or `std::vector` instead.

Comment: You don't need the EOF check, as the condition in the `while` loop will fail when EOF is encountered.

Comment: Your inner `while` loop should be based on the length of the string not for a terminating nul character.  The `std::string` does not require a terminating nul character.  The `line[j]` may be true after the last character in the string and may continue into unknown memory locations until a '\0' is found (very bad).

Comment: can you please show the calling code, how is that array set up?

Comment: You seem to believe that calling `std::istringstream::str()` resets the stream state. It doesn't. You'll need to call `clear()` to do so. BTW, changing one character for another is done using something like `std::replace(line.begin(), line.end(), ';', ' ');`

Comment: Thanks for all the tips, the issue was indeed that I wasn't calling clear to reset the istringstream state. After I introduced that to my code it's working perfectly.